# Selenium Webdriver give NoSuchFrameException

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select the frame in the web page and it failed to select frame in Selenium IDE. And when I use the Webdriver, it comes an `NoSuchFrameException`:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("GO").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("EO_PE_SRCH_INP_EO_PE_URLTEXT$5").click()
driver.switch_to.frame("contentFrame")
```

> driver.switch_to.frame("contentFrame")   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py",
>   line 64, in frame
>       self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 173, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 166, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame: contentFrame
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame (file:///var/folders/nk/l6lw3w5917l99dl9vs0g6z_m0000gn/T/tmp4NI1ne/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9710:11)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/nk/l6lw3w5917l99dl9vs0g6z_m0000gn/T/tmp4NI1ne/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:16)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/nk/l6lw3w5917l99dl9vs0g6z_m0000gn/T/tmp4NI1ne/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:548:5)

HTML code:

```
<head></head>
<frameset id="fm2" frameborder="0" cols="150,*" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame src="https://xxxxxxxxxxx/servlet/Main/menu" scrolling="yes" name="mainMenuFrame"></frame>
    <frame noresize="" name="contentFrame" src="https://xxxxx/servlet/Main/main?usertype=2">
        #document
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Are you trying to switch to contentFrame from top window or from another frame? If its another frame switch to default content then perform switch to contentFrame...

Comment: Actually, when i clicked "EO_PE_SRCH_INP_EO_PE_URLTEXT$5", a new window will pop up and i want to select the contentFrame in the new window

Comment: If clicking "EO_PE_SRCH_INP_EO_PE_URLTEXT$5" opens a new window den u need to switch to that window first and then switch to frame. U r directly switching to frame without switching to the window. That will definetly give you error cause contentFrame is not available in main window, its in the child window that popped up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `frameset` you are dealing with, make it in two steps:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("fm2")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.switch_to.frame("contentFrame")
```

You can also [wait for the frame explicitly](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fm2")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.switch_to.frame("contentFrame")
```

---

UPDATE (using a real-world example provided in comments):

It appears that you need to switch to the frame *by index*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.ihp.hku.hk/sfb.html')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "frameset")))
driver.switch_to.frame(1)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Badminton: max 4 persons per court').click()
```

Comment: The contentFrame still cannot be found. Actually I can execute the command selectframe to select the contentFrame in IDE seperately, but it will fail to run the command when I run the case from beginning in IDE.

Comment: @ChunYinNg what about the second option that includes the wait? Do you get any exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//frame[@name='contentFrame']")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I face the same error

frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fm2")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @ChunYinNg then I'm not sure what is happening, it is difficult to guess without reproducing it on my own. Is it possible to share the link to the web-site?

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot do that because account and  password are needed to access the link

Comment: I found a link to skip the login part. URL: ihp.hku.hk/sfb.html Actually, I just want to click the item (like Individual Exercise) but I even cannot click that

Comment: @mt246 the link was very helpful - see the updated answer - you just need to switch to the frame by index.